# how to know whether service bus triggered function completed succesfully?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

**Has my function completed processing successfully?**

Under 0.01% of the time, I am seeing exceptions like the following:

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException:    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__19.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> 293)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 97) Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Antrox.antrox_dg_func_dev+d__0.MoveNext (Antrox, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullAntrox, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
> C:\sourcecode\Interfaces\Alidade\Antrox\MAIN\Antrox\antrox_dg_func_dev.csAntrox,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 67)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\VoidTaskMethodInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 20)    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 52)    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__27.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> 545)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__26.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> 492)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__25.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> 436)    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult
> (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__19.MoveNext
> (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
> 245)

Here's the code:

```
namespace aaa {
    public static class aaa_dg_func_dev {
        [FunctionName ("CheckMessageServiceBusTopicTriggered")]
        public static async Task Run ([ServiceBusTrigger (
                "%Topic%",
                "%Subscription%",
                Connection = "ServiceBus")] string @in, [Table ("%HashTable%", "%InboundInterfaceProperty%", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudTable hashes, [ServiceBus ("%OutputTopic%", Connection = "ServiceBus", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)] IAsyncCollector<Message> bus,
            IDictionary<string, object> UserProperties,
            string messageId,
            ILogger log) {
            var sourceKey = GetEnvironmentVariable ("InboundInterfaceKey");
            var sourceFileKey = GetEnvironmentVariable ("SourceFileNameKey");
            var threshold = GetEnvironmentVariable ("threshold");
            var sourceFile = UserProperties[sourceFileKey].ToString ();
            var source = UserProperties[sourceKey].ToString ();
            var hash = Hash (@in);
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var @out = new Message {
                Body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (@in),
                MessageId = messageId
            };
            @out.UserProperties.Add (sourceKey, source);
            @out.UserProperties.Add (sourceFileKey, sourceFile);

            var get = Retrieve<MessageHash> (source, hash);
            var hashResult = await hashes.ExecuteAsync (get);

            //If there are no records found, then insert and send message
            if (hashResult.Result == null) {
                var hashMessage = new MessageHash (source, hash, now.ToString (), sourceFile);
                var insert = Insert (hashMessage);
                await hashes.ExecuteAsync (insert);
                await bus.AddAsync (@out);
                return;
            }

            //Perform upsert operation on existing hash to update lastmodified
            var thresholdEnd = now;
            var thresholdStart = now.AddDays (-int.Parse (GetEnvironmentVariable ("threshold")));
            var found = (MessageHash) hashResult.Result;
            var orgLastModified = DateTime.Parse (found.LastModified);
            found.LastModified = now.ToString ();
            found.SourceFileName = sourceFile;
            var upsert = Replace (found);
            await hashes.ExecuteAsync (upsert);
            //Return if we are within the threshold
            if (orgLastModified >= thresholdStart && orgLastModified <= thresholdEnd) {
                return;
            }

            //Send message
            await bus.AddAsync (@out);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the telemetry on the function:

[image]

Here's one full operation:

[image]

**When these storage exceptions happen, is the message requeued?**

Comment: In default, Azure function use PeekLock mode to receive messages.  It calls `Complete` on the message if the function finishes successfully, or calls `Abandon` to resend the message to the queue if the function fails. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#peeklock-behavior and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk#receive-mode

Comment: @JimXu you are saying `Complete` or `Abandon` will not show up in the logs at all?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?